# Flutter - Image shadow fails on widget resize

Tags: flutter, dart, shadow

I want to do this kind of layout, with a shadow around the image :
[image: layout]

I use a Container around the Image, with a BoxDecoration to draw the shadow.
The image should resize when the Column shrinks.

But the shadow doesn't resize with the image :

[image]

Can someone help me ?

Here is my code :

```
Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
            Text(...)             
            ),
          ]),
          Expanded(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 2.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                      spreadRadius: 0,
                      blurRadius: 0,
                      offset: Offset(5, 5), 
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Image.asset("images/myimage.png")),
          )),
          Text("..."),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              IconButton(...),
              IconButton(...),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: I would try removing the `Expanded` around your image container. `Expanded` is telling it to take up as much space as possible which doesn't seem like what you want here.

Answer (score 1):

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Text(...),
    Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(width: 2.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                spreadRadius: 0,
                blurRadius: 10,
                offset: Offset(5, 5),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: Image.asset(
              "images/myimage.png",
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Text("..."),
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        IconButton(...),
        IconButton(...),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```